# iOS Google Maps SDK vs MapKit scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, mapkit

When I try to integrate Google Maps SDK to my iOS app - i get it working, but scrolling of the map is too laggy (even on 6s device). At the same time i have very smooth scrolling when using MapKit, but MapKit does not display houses and their numbers (it's important for my app). I wanted to know, is scrolling in Google Maps laggy for everybody or maybe I've done something wrong? Native Google Maps application has smooth scrolling though.

Comment: post your implementation

Comment: Scrolling is lagging for me even with Google demo project (pod try GoogleMaps)

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get addresses of the houses you are tracking in map. I think thats the the reason you are using google map.
So the thing you are trying to do is that every time you shift the map to get a address of a specific location a network request is made. Thats why map is getting laggy beacause this is done in the `main-thread`.
So the solution is to do the address-thing in another thread not the main thread, use callback or blocks.

Comment: I'm not doing any requests on scroll. I tried Google demo project (pod try GoogleMaps) and it also lagging when scrolling, but google maps application hasn't got this problem.